# Can TextViews be clipped both horizontally and vertically in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView that I want to clip both horizontally and vertically.

```
<TextView android:layout_width="10dip" android:text=""
  android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical" 
  android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal">
</TextView>
```

but of course that's invalid XML.

Is there any way of combining these within the XML file? I can see from the documentation that the switches are bitmap fields. I guess what I want something like:

```
view.layout_gravity = Gravity.CLIP_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL
```

but without having to dismember the Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical"
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil!
That mechanism of combining attributes appears to be working.
As it happens, my particular need was solved by mucking with the padding. (I clearly need to do a little more research on clipping as it is not behaving the way I expect)